# tflite_convert a Keras h5 model which has a custom loss function results in a ValueError, even if I add it in the Keras losses import

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I have written a SRGAN implementation. In the entry point class of the Python program, I declare a function which returns a mean square using the VGG19 model:

```
# <!--- COST FUNCTION --->
def build_vgg19_loss_network(ground_truth_image, predicted_image):
    loss_model = Vgg19Loss.define_loss_model(high_resolution_shape)
    return mean(square(loss_model(ground_truth_image) - loss_model(predicted_image)))

import keras.losses
keras.losses.build_vgg19_loss_network = build_vgg19_loss_network
# <!--- /COST FUNCTION --->
```

(`Vgg19Loss` class shown further below)

As you can see, I have added this custom loss function in the import `keras.losses`. Why? Because I thought it could solve the following problem...: When I execute the command `tflite_convert --output_file=srgan.tflite --keras_model_file=srgan.h5`, the Python interpreter raises this error:

> raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ':' + object_name)
>   ValueError: Unknown loss function:build_vgg19_loss_network

**However, it didn't solve the problem. Any other solution which could work?**

Here is the `Vgg19Loss` class:

```
from keras import Model
from keras.applications import VGG19


class Vgg19Loss:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def define_loss_model(high_resolution_shape):
        model_vgg19 = VGG19(False, 'imagenet', input_shape=high_resolution_shape)
        model_vgg19.trainable = False
        for l in model_vgg19.layers:
            l.trainable = False
        loss_model = Model(model_vgg19.input, model_vgg19.get_layer('block5_conv4').output)
        loss_model.trainable = False
        return loss_model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code you posted the following way:

```py
from keras import Model
from keras.applications import VGG19
import keras.backend as K


class Vgg19Loss:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def define_loss_model(high_resolution_shape):
        model_vgg19 = VGG19(False, 'imagenet', input_shape=high_resolution_shape)
        model_vgg19.trainable = False
        for l in model_vgg19.layers:
            l.trainable = False
        loss_model = Model(model_vgg19.input, model_vgg19.get_layer('block5_conv4').output)
        loss_model.trainable = False
        return loss_model


def build_vgg19_loss_network(ground_truth_image, predicted_image):
    loss_model = Vgg19Loss.define_loss_model(high_resolution_shape) # where is this variable coming from?
    return K.mean(K.square(loss_model(ground_truth_image) - loss_model(predicted_image)))

import keras.losses
keras.losses.build_vgg19_loss_network = build_vgg19_loss_network

print(keras.losses.build_vgg19_loss_network)  # <function build_vgg19_loss_network at 0x7f05e8e1cbf8>
```

I get no error messages and the function is assigned to the losses module. That means the problematic lines are probably not part of what you posted. It would be nice to know which line of code raises the error that you quoted.

However, I'm not sure where this `high_resolution_shape` argument on line 22 in your `build_vgg_19_network` function is coming from. If this is a global constant, it should be written in all uppercase letters separated by underscores to prevent confusion. If it is not defined it will throw a NameError sooner or later.

If I execute `keras.losses.build_vgg19_loss_network(None, None)` after running the code above, I get the following error message:

> NameError: name 'high_resolution_shape' is not defined

**Edit:** If this error happens only during TFLite conversion, it does so because custom objects are not yet supported by the TFLiteConverter in tensorflow 1.x. However, there is a [commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/09deaeb03ca4ceb40cf600a337083e2054e65390) on the tensorflow Github repo that addresses this issue and adds support for custom objects (see also the related [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/24394)). It should be part of the official [tensorflow v2.0.0-beta1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta1).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Running the program with Python2 or 3 works indeed. But executing the command line `tflite_convert` doesn't because this program supports only a small set of Python's features. My program isn't bound to any error related to Python interpreter, but is actually related to TFLiteConverter.

Comment: Hi @JarsOfJam-Scheduler, now I understand. Thank you for explaining that again. I edited my answer regarding this issue.

Comment: Where would one download TFLiteConverter, v.2.0.0-beta1? (for ubuntu)

Comment: The release can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta1). You should be able to install it with `pip install https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/archive/v2.0.0-beta1.zip`

Comment: Hmmm it rises this error: "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-btnkc8v4-build/"

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler This is an installation issue now. You can try `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1` instead. Also, `pip install --upgrade setuptools` is always worth a try as well. Let me know if any of this helps-

Comment: Hum I don't understand why installing tensorflow 2.0.0-beta1 would allow me to install TFLiteConverter 2.0.0-beta1?

Comment: Until April, TFLite did not support custom classes. However, in April a contributor changed several lines in [lite.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py) so that it supports custom classes. These changes were released with tensorflow v2.0.0-beta1. Earlier versions of tensorflow don't have these changes included and thereby don't support custom classes. It is this script that gets called when you run `tflite_convert`. That means, if you do not have v2.0.0-beta1 or above you don't have support for custom classes.

Comment: Well I've installing this version of tensorflow. Thanks to the command `pip list`, I'm now sure that only tensorflow 2.0.0b1 is installed. However, I still get the same error, "raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ':' + object_name)
ValueError: Unknown loss function:build_vgg19_loss_network".

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler Hmm, could you try to disable tensorflow 2 behaviour with `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` and then `tf.disable_v2_behavior()`? It seems like there is a [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c4d152c61235900d8bee7f672e15abd732459ef4/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py#L217) in v2.0.0-beta1 where tensorflow still ignores custom classes when v2 flags are enabled.

Comment: I've added these two lines at the beginning of my Launcher.py ( https://github.com/Jars-of-jam-Scheduler/downgraded_srgan ) but the error is still there. Any idea ? :(

Comment: I'll have a look at it.